# How to set Packer variables in HCL2

Tags: packer, hcl

I am new to packer and need help to understand the `variables` usage

so I have a main `build.pck.hcl` file with `source` and other sections where I want to use variables defined in another file like this:

```
...
client_id = var.client_id
...
```

I created another file for variables only:

`account.pkr.hcl`

```
variable "client_id" {
    type = string
}
```

the I start `packer` like this:

```
packer build -color=false -debug  -var "client_id=123" -var-file account.pkr.hcl build.pck.hcl
```

but I always get an error while running:

```
Error: Variable declaration in a .pkrvar file

  on account.pkr.hcl line 14, in variable "client_id":
  14: variable "client_id" {

A .pkrvar file is used to assign values to variables that have already been
declared in .pkr files, not to declare new variables. To declare variable
"client_id", place this block in one of your .pkr files, such as
variables.pkr.hcl

To set a value for this variable in account.pkr.hcl, use the definition syntax
instead:
    client_id = <value>
```

What I am missing ? How to fix that ?

I want to some variables have `default` value and some of them will be passed on command line

P.S. If I changed `packer build` command and pass a folder path where files are I get an error:

```
Error: Undefined -var variable

A "client_id" variable was passed in the command line but was not found in known
variables. To declare variable "client_id", place this block in one of your .pkr
files, such as variables.pkr.hcl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `-var-file` because you think you need to tell packer where to find that file. In reality, you don't need to do that and you simply need to use `.` as a context when running `packer build`, as packer will load all files ending in `.pkr.hcl`.

The following should work for you:

```
$ packer build -color=false -debug -var "client_id=123" .
```